# Sample size determination for block design with repeated measurement in SAS

Tags: anova

I have a design where birds of 1, 3, 5 week of age are placed in 2 chambers(independent) with 4 treatments( light technology) for 4 days. for example, x no of birds of 1 weeks of age are kept for 4 days and then new birds of 3 week age are placed in both chambers and so on...readings are taken for their position, feed consumption/day/bird etc. I need to calculate the sample size required. I am using Proc GLMpower in SAS, using twowayanova to calculate the sample size but I am not sure how to account for repeated measurement for 4 days. Also, Can you suggest any other way to do this type power analysis. I tried in G*Power as well but not quite sure how it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When problems get more complicated than the simple cases that have nice canned sample size solutions I turn to simulation.  The basic steps:

1. Decide what you think your data will look like (including things you may want to change, e.g. sample size(s))
2. Decide how you will analyze the data
3. create some code that simulates the data and analyzes it then returns the p-value or other statistic of interest
4. run the code in step 3 a bunch of times on a given set of conditions, then see how often the null hypothesis is rejected, this is your power (or an estimate of the power).
5. change the conditions and run again, ...

In SAS you could probably create the data in proc IML, then send it to proc GLM or such for the analysis, use ODS to save the p-value, then capture this back in IML, etc.  However, I think R is more straight forward for this (but I use R much more than SAS these days, so could be biased).